# How to capture Memory usage on Elasticbeanstalk using Cloudwatch Logs on Linux instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have read the AWS docs on Elasticbeanstalk logging and the Cloudwatch agent and it seems the cloudwatch agent should be reporting memory usage (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/metrics-collected-by-CloudWatch-agent.html) but this dosn't seem to be happening for me. 
when i go into the Cloudwatch -> metrics -> ec2 i can't see anything related to memory. cpu, network etc is collected but not memory.

The platform version i am using is "PHP 7.2 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.8.7"

All the googling seems to indicate that you need to run custom scripts (perl) to get that info, but the article linked above seems to contradict that.

in my .ebextensions folder i have a .config file that turns on the logs. i am also able to send custom application logs without issue.

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    option_name: StreamLogs
    value: true
```

am i missing an argument somewhere?

Edit: After a bit more research i dont think the "enable log streaming" option i have set actually uses the cloudwatch agent,  `/usr/bin/aws logs...` is running on the server. so i guess that option enables log pushing via the aws cli?

i have done some googling and can not find an exampled of how to install the cloud watch agent using .ebextentions. i could try my self but if no one else is doing it that way am i thinking about it wrong?

Comment: I'm using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-cw.html but so far I can't see any Custom Metrics in CloudWatch.

Comment: Ah. Now I see I had made an incorrect change to the .ebextensions config example they gave. I reverted back to what they gave and am now seeing the Linux System custom metrics.